# Create and update same or different entity record in single ExecuteTransactionRequest or ExecuteMultipleRequest

Tags: transactions, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to **Create and Update** *OR* **Update and Delete** records on single or multiple entities in single transaction so that if any co-related transaction gets failed other should be rolled back.

I have tried to search over the net but didn't have luck on this. Is there any possible way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit more trials and error I was able to solve this issue. The solution which I'm providing here may not be recommended to all as it I have created **GUID** in the code. So there might be a performance issue as we creating **GUID** on the code rather than auto-create in DB side. But yes, this solution worked for me.

```
            OrganizationRequest req1 = new OrganizationRequest();
            req1.RequestName = "Create";
            Guid newAccountId = Guid.NewGuid();
            var account = new Account()
            {
                Name = "Acme, Inc.",
                Id = newAccountId
            };
            req1.Parameters.Add("Target", account);

            // Create second account
            OrganizationRequest req2 = new OrganizationRequest();
            account.Name = "Updated name of Acme, Inc.";
            req2.RequestName = "Update";
            req2.Parameters.Add("Target", account);

            // Using Execute Multiple 
            ExecuteTransactionRequest multipleRequest = new ExecuteTransactionRequest();
            multipleRequest.Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection();
            multipleRequest.Requests.Add(req1);
            multipleRequest.Requests.Add(req2);

            var responseForRecords = (ExecuteTransactionResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(multipleRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the below code to test if a Create and Update is possible in a transaction. It appears that the answer is, "No".

It fails because the UpdateRequest doesn't have access to the Id of the Account that got created earlier in the transaction. Update and Delete seems like it should be possible.

On the Create and Update scenario you're dealing with, would it be possible to apply the logic of the Update before creating the record?

```
var transReq = new ExecuteTransactionRequest()
{
    // Create an empty organization request collection.
    Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection(),
    ReturnResponses = true
};

var account = new Account()
{
    Name = "Acme, Inc."
};

var createReq = new CreateRequest
{
    Target = account
};

transReq.Requests.Add(createReq);

account.NumberOfEmployees = 100;

var updateReq = new UpdateRequest
{
    Target = account
};

transReq.Requests.Add(updateReq);

var response = (ExecuteTransactionResponse)svc.Execute(transReq);
```

Please check this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt634414.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have tried the same reference and also tried to play with it around but I was not able to do so that's why I need the guidance that if we can do it or not in the very first place.

Comment: But can I update the different entity here? For example. what if we try to Create the account record in 1st request and update the existing Contact record in 2nd request and add it in transReq. Is it possible? If yes, can you update your accordingly for a sample?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, here's the example to update a contact after creating the Account. As far as I can tell, the limitation still exists that the Account Id is unavailable in the 2nd request inside the transaction.

My conclusion is: yes, you can update the Contact, as long as you're not looking to associate it to the Account you created in the same transaction.

```
var transReq = new ExecuteTransactionRequest()
{
    // Create an empty organization request collection.
    Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection(),
    ReturnResponses = true
};

var account = new Account()
{
    Name = "Acme, Inc.",
    EntityState = EntityState.Created
};

var createReq = new CreateRequest
{
    Target = account
};

transReq.Requests.Add(createReq);

var contact = getContacts().First();  //Get a contact however you want
contact.JobTitle = "President";
contact.EntityState = EntityState.Changed;

var updateReq = new UpdateRequest
{
    Target = contact
};

transReq.Requests.Add(updateReq);

var response = (ExecuteTransactionResponse)svc.Execute(transReq);
```

Other articles of interest:

http://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2015/04/19/New-CRM-SDK-Feature---Transactional-Batching

https://nishantrana.me/2016/07/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328075.aspx